# Помогите построить цикл

Tags: python, циклы, блок-схема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PYTHON

Помогите построить цикл, не пойму как после условия перейти на код, который был написан до. После первой проверки(false), должно произойти повторное вычисление, а так же после второй проверки(true), должны произойти эти же вычисления

Comment: посмотреть какие виды циклов бывают в нужном языке и выбрать из них подходящий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
while True:
    ...
    if |T-τ| < Δτ/2 :
        ...
        if T >= Tкон :
            break
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !)